# Android - Load a HTTP URL without showing anything of the page?

Tags: android, html, request

This may sound quite specific, but I hope someone could help me. It would be greatly appreciated. I have a project I'm working on with Arduino, whereby (for the moment), I'd like to have an Android device, send data to the Arduino, then the Arduino will display it on an LCD screen. I have the Arduino stuff totally done, so it's just the Android stuff getting me stuck. The way I load data onto the Arduino it by sending requests in the URL, so for example I would put 
`http://IP_ADDR/?1=VARIABLE_ONE&2=VARIABLE_TWO`. 
However I have no idea how to do this on Android, and most HTTP tutorials are discussing POST and GET methods in HTML. I was wondering if there was a way for me to just send a request to that ip, with the variables inside it, but not show the actual web-page on the device?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, request a permission to access network, add following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then the easiest way is to use Apache http client bundled with Android:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://IP_ADDR/?1=VARIABLE_ONE&2=VARIABLE_TWO"));
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    out.close();
} else{
    //Closes the connection.
    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
}
```

This way you just execute the query without getting any response

Comment: I've been trying this. However, the Arduino shows no network requests. I'm not 100% sure which end this is on, but I have a feeling it is Android.